# Why are interface variables implicitly static in Java?

Tags: java, interface, static, final

I've read posts that said something like:
"A java constant is a static final variable"

I don't really understand why this is true. Why isn't marking it as final enough?

Why do we need to add the "static" modifier? If it's a final field inside an interface it's already immutable and is shared among all implementing classes.

I'd appreciate if someone could clear this up for me.

Comment: You don't need to add the static modifier in an interface. Are you asking the question in your title or the question in your text?

Answer (score 2):

Since interfaces store constants, the variables are declared `public static final`.
Now, it is fairly intuitive:

1. Constant values do not change, hence the final.
2. All the classes implementing the interface must have only one value for the constant values. hence the `static`
3. And `public` cause everyone must get the access to constant values.

Here is what the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) says:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any
>   or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Comment: Isn't that opposite? Weren't interfaces used to store constant values because its fields are `public static final`?

Comment: @Pshemo Have a look at the edit. Better ?